# Add id attribute to <table> tag using PrimeNG p-table

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable

I need to add an ID to the `table`, I'm using PrimeNG so I don't have this table tag in my component, only the `p-table`.
I tried `[id]` and `[attr.id]` but without success.

Any other suggestions please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this way:

1. Mark p-table with an id for accessing his reference in ngAfterViewInit method:

   ```
   <p-table #pTableId></p-table>
   ```
2. Then in Component.ts :

   ```
   import {Table} from 'primeng/table';
   export class MyComponent  {
       @ViewChild('pTableId') pTableRef: Table;

       ngAfterViewInit() {
           const table = this.pTableRef.el.nativeElement.querySelector('table');
           table.setAttribute('id', 'myTableId');
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to add this id? 
You can do something like this

```html
 <p-table #some-id> </p-table>
```

and in your component

```js
@ViewChild('some-id') myTable: any;
```

You can Refer to the table in your function (this.myTable) and look for children if that's what you are looking for.
Let me know if that helped

Comment: It's a QA requirement.
This solution doesn't help since I don't have the table as a child of my table and I don't have access to it.